# Populating a ComboBox in WinForms CLI/CLR with open processes

Tags: c++, winforms

Ive been working on a C++ WinForms project for a while now, but have run into a wall. I'm familiar with how to populate a comboBox in a C# Winforms, however that same method doesn't seem to apply for the C++ variant.

I'd generally do it with something like this:

```
Process[] allProc = Process.GetProcesses(); 
  foreach (Process p in allProc)
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
     }
```

But Visual Studio doesn't like that I'm attempting to create an array of processes. Any sort of help would be much appreciated, I am at a complete loss.

Comment: is this one of Microsoft's variations of C++? C++ `foreach` doesn't look like that

Comment: as far as I'm aware, the CLI/CLR WinForms uses the regular C++ conventions. However the code example I've shared is in C#, to show the method of which I'm most familiar with.

Comment: so why not show the code that isn't working?

Comment: The code that isn't working looks like this:

```
Process[] allProc = Process::GetProcesses(); 
  for each (Process p in allProc)
     {
         listBox1->Items->Add(p.ProcessName);
     }
```

Comment: `listBox1->DisplayMember = "ProcessName"; listBox1->DataSource = Process::GetProcesses();` -- If you want the Array, it's just `array<Process^>^ allProc = Process::GetProcesses();`

Comment: `Process[] allProc` is not a valid way to declare an array in C++.

Comment: @user253751 The OP already mentioned that this is the C# syntax that should be *translated*,I assume in C++/CLI.

Comment: @Jimi and then said the C++ version also used `Process[] allProc`

Comment: @user253751 The non-working attempt is using that syntax, which is of course not valid in either C++ or C++/CLI.

Comment: If, as it appears (`ListBox`, `Process` etc.), you're using C++/CLI, you can write `auto allProc = Process::GetProcesses();`, which works somewhat like `var` in C#. -- Tag the question with the language you're actually using. C++/CLI and C++ are not the same.

Comment: @Jimi: He said he's more familiar with C#.  Nowhere did he say that the code in his C++ question is actually in C#.  Well, nowhere in the question....

Comment: Foo[] is syntax for an unmanaged array.  Such an array cannot store Process objects, the garbage collector can't find them back.  Proper syntax is `array<Process^>^ allProc = Process::GetProcesses();`.  Knowing when to use the ^ hat is superduper important, very hard to make progress in C++/CLI if that's still a mystery.  Tutorials a plenty.